# word unexpected (expecting "then") in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Hello this is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
service=dmsspeechbatch-0.0.jar #(name of the service)
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "$service is running"
else
cd /application/TextToSpeech/dmsspeechbatch
nohup java -jar target/dmsspeechbatch-0.0.jar &
fi
```

I am getting this error

> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the leading spaces in the shebang line a typo/copy-paste-error?

Comment: that is a copy paste error

Comment: In that case `speechbatch1.sh` is executed and the rest of the script not. You should post `speechbatch1.sh` as well.

Comment: speechbatch1.sh is the file i posted here

Comment: Can u try remove \r from your script?
Actually everything is ok in the script.

Comment: sorry, what is \r ?

Comment: hidden symbol, you can try to do autochange in the advanced mode in notepad ++

Comment: can you merge if and then line like this **if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ));then** and try?

Comment: That error message looks a dash error, not one that bash would print. Exactly how are you running this script (and on what OS/release)?

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` this line:

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
```

should be

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
```

Also this line can be optimised like this:

```
if [ $(pgrep $service | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
```

and also remove the leading spaces in first line

Comment: Why? `((` is a bashism, right, but in `bash` it's completely correct.

Comment: @iokanuon, I am not familiar with the word  "bashism"

Comment: it means a bash-specific feature, not present in most POSIX compliant shells.

Comment: @iokanuon, i see, thank you for clarification. Usually my intention is to write scripts as portable as possible

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @adityadokhale, I checked it and it work fine for me. Please add in your question the distribution you use and the version of bash

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Comment: @adityadokhale, your script work fine. Please check if you do not have inside some control characters. And you can try to copy the text from your question and paste it in editor and try with this new file.